# ipywidgets install issue on python

Tags: python, ipywidgets, tqdm

I tried to install 'ipywidgets' on my Python. I used both 'pip install ipywidgets' and 'pip3 install ipywidgets'
but neither is working.
Can you please help me how to install ipywidgets? It needs for tqdm.

I have a long error log as below:

```
Installing collected packages: pywinpty, pandocfilters, nbclient, mistune, jupyterlab-pygments, jinja2, ipython, entrypoints, defusedxml, cffi, bleach, terminado, Send2Trash, prometheus-client, nbconvert, ipykernel, argon2-cffi, notebook, widgetsnbextension, jupyterlab-widgets, ipywidgets
    Running setup.py install for pywinpty ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\mpa3209794\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MPA3209794\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8y79y8w4\\pywinpty_b841185b2a294deca64a008a83fa371c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MPA3209794\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8y79y8w4\\pywinpty_b841185b2a294deca64a008a83fa371c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MPA3209794\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-izffzjgx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\mpa3209794\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pywinpty'
         cwd: C:\Users\MPA3209794\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8y79y8w4\pywinpty_b841185b2a294deca64a008a83fa371c\
    Complete output (25 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
    copying winpty\ptyprocess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
    copying winpty\winpty_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
    copying winpty\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\test_cywinpty.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\test_ptyprocess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\test_winpty_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\_winpty
    copying winpty\_winpty\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\_winpty
    running build_ext
    building 'winpty.cywinpty' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\winpty
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\mpa3209794\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\mpa3209794\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcwinpty/cywinpty.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\winpty/cywinpty.obj
    cywinpty.c
    winpty/cywinpty.c(629): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\mpa3209794\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MPA3209794\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8y79y8w4\\pywinpty_b841185b2a294deca64a008a83fa371c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MPA3209794\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8y79y8w4\\pywinpty_b841185b2a294deca64a008a83fa371c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MPA3209794\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-izffzjgx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\mpa3209794\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pywinpty' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: *I used both 'pip install ipwidgets'*   <- if you literally did that, you are missing a 'y' in ipywidgets

Comment: that's my typo when I write this thread

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing with [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution)? Try installing only ipywidgets and notebook before installing other packages. Install anaconda and then create a new conda environment with

`conda create -c conda-forge -n [name] ipywidgets notebook` where `[name]` is the name you can choose for your environment. The two packages `ipywidgets` and `notebook` will be installed to start.

`conda activate [name]` to switch to the newly created environment

`ipython kernel install --name [name] --display-name "[name]" --sys-prefix` to install the kernel.
Now you should be able to run jupyter notebook and verify ipywidgets is working correctly.